# MySQL query is running but not running

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Alright let me explain myself here:

I am making an online text based game.  I have a page where 3 things can happen:

They can create a position

Can edit a position

Can delete a position

So far I have creating a position working.  I moved on deleting a position next.  All was good and I got no errors, no warnings, etc.. And when I ran it, it came back to the screen it was supposed to after the script to delete the position ran.  It is only supposed to come here after the query runs.

Well nothing happened and after 3 hours of trying crap I'm coming to you guys b/c I'm on my last leg.  I still have no critical errors, nothing is making it fail:  Here is my code.

```
<?php
//In the include file is the connection to the db
include("library/new_library.php");

//Below is the session id, gets their position id from the DB, than grabs whether or not they can edit the company
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$sql = "SELECT ID, PositionID FROM users WHERE ID = '$user_id'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $position = $row['PositionID'];
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCPositions WHERE PositionID = '$position'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $editCompany = $row['Edit_Company'];
}


//Next I check for position edit and if they try to put in the position id of a position the company does not control it gives them a "nice" message.
$company = $_SESSION['company'];
if($_GET['pidedit']){
    $position = $_GET['pidedit'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCPositions WHERE PositionID = '$position'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        if($row['CompanyID'] != $company)
        {
            $warning = "<div class='warning'>You are trying to edit a position that does not belong to your company.  DO NOT TRY TO CHEAT THE SYSTEM!</div>";
        }
        else
        {
            $positionArray[] = array(ID => $row['PositionID'], name => $row['Name'], hire => $row['Hire'], fire => $row['Fire'], bid => $row['Contract'], edit => $row['Edit_Company'], finances => $row['Finances']);
        }
    }
}

//Here I check for $_GET delete
elseif($_GET['piddelete'])
{
    $position = $_GET['piddelete'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCPositions WHERE PositionID = '$position'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        if($row['CompanyID'] != $company)
        {
            $warning = "<div class='warning'>You are trying to delete a position that does not belong to your company.  DO NOT TRY TO CHEAT THE SYSTEM!</div>";
        }
    }
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblCPositions WHERE CompanyID = '$company'";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    $number = mysql_num_rows($query);
    $numberLeft = 12 - $number;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $positionArray[] = array(ID => $row['PositionID'], name => $row['Name'], hire => $row['Hire'], fire => $row['Fire'], bid => $row['Contract'], edit => $row['Edit_Company'], finances => $row['Finances']);
    }
}

//
if($_POST['submitNewPosition'])
{
    $name = $_POST['positionName'];
    $hire = $_POST['hire'];
    $fire = $_POST['fire'];
    $bid = $_POST['bid'];
    $edit = $_POST['edit'];
    $finances = $_POST['finances'];
    $cid = $_SESSION['company'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblCPositions(CompanyID, Name, Hire, Fire, Contract, Edit_Company, Finances) VALUES ('$cid','$name','$hire','$fire','$bid','$edit','$finances')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);
    if($query)
    {
        header("location: view_company.php?newp=success");
    }
}

//Haven't finished this section yet
if($_POST['submitEditPosition'])
{
    $name = $_POST['positionName'];
    $fire = $_POST['hire'];
    $fire = $_POST['fire'];
    $bid = $_POST['bid'];
    $edit = $_POST['edit'];
    $finances = $_POST['finances'];
}

//This this is my problem area, this is where it says its running the query but its not.
if(isset($_POST['deletePosition']))
{
    $deleteID = $_GET['piddelete'];
    $deleteSql = "DELETE FROM tblCPositions WHERE PositionID = '$deleteID'";
    $deleteQuery = mysql_query($deleteSql);
    if($deleteQuery)
    {
        header("location: view_company.php?delete=success");
    }
    if(!$deleteQuery)
    {
        header("location: view_company.php?delete=failure");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** -

Ok so I got it working the problem was something I forgot, this form was just meant to be a "yes or no form" so I was doing post only to post the submit button, nothing else was on the form.  What I had forgot was on the action="file.php" (what I had) I had forgotten to pass on the get variable so once I changed it to action="file.php?piddelete=12" it worked.

Thanks for everyones help I really appreciate it.

Comment: Must say very interesting title :)

Comment: uhm, have you checked wethere error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED is set?

Comment: yeah it is but I couldn't think of any other way to explain it, I'll write back with the error reporting.

Comment: try adding an `ELSE` statement within the section you labeled as your "problem area" to help debug.

Comment: Nothing...still went to the success.

Comment: @codaddict This must be a special [Schrödinger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger%27s_cat)'s mysql query :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 to 1 your variable `$_GET['piddelete'];` is empty.  What do you get when you do this:

```
var_dump($_GET['piddelete']);
```

Disable the header redirect so that you can see the output.

**edit**

Or, as Nick pointed out, you can add `die()` statements to your queries:

```
$deleteQuery = mysql_query($deleteSql) or die(mysql_error());
```

If your query still runs, and the script doesn't die, and the position is *still* not deleted, you should check the query, it may be deleting `0` rows successfully.  try killing at `die($deleteSql);` and run the query through MySQL's console.

**/edit**

Also, I'm compelled to introduce you to my good friend [SQL injection attack](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html).  You should filter all data contained in the `$_POST` and `$_GET` superglobals before handing them over to the MySQL server.  use [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Try to grok this:

```
whatever.com/your_url.php?pidedit=x'%3B%20DROP%20TABLE%20tblCPositions%3B%20--
```

If I were to execute that query string on your application, your `tblCPositions` table would be dropped.

Comment: Just checked and its set, in the url it is set and I'm able to echo the $_GET variable on the page where the button is to delete the page.

Comment: How about that error reporting?  Also, is your above script on the same page as the delete button?  If not, (I'm guessing it's not since you are doing a redirect) you'll need to check if the GET variable is set on *that* script, not the one before it.  Disable the header redirect, echo the `GET` variable in the above script, and click the button.

Comment: Yeah I try to get stuff working without it first then I add mysql_real_escape_string...I know its not normal but it works for me most of the time :)  

Well, actually the get isn't coming from a form.  Its coming from text I enter so yes it is on the same page but its not from a form.

Comment: That's dangerous.  What if you forget?  Just *one*.

Comment: As far as Error_Reporting goes, it is set to go to log errors in a file.

Ok just checked and was able to echo that variable without any issues :(

Comment: Also, I think it would be easier to just do this:
$sql = mysql_query("Your query") or die (mysql_error());

Comment: Ok I just tried something:

I moved the delete part of the script to its own page, and made the form method Get.  I did a var_dump on piddelete (the url was domain.com/file.php?piddelete=12) and this is what it outputed:  

    string(2) "12"

Comment: Okay, so it works *outside* your current script, but that doesn't mean it works *inside* it.

Comment: Ok I got it, on the form action I was doing the name of the page so like: file.php  but I wasn't passing the parameter along.  <---Better explination above, thanks a lot stephen and I'll get to work on that security :D